# How to add implemetation of RequestDataValueProcessor using code and not as xml configuration

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-security

I have a bean like follows

```
<bean name="requestDataValueProcessor"    class="com.bom.DOMRequestDataValueProcessor"/>
```

DOMRequestDataValueProcessor implements the RequestDataValueProcessor.

I am doing my mvc configuration using the following class and not by xml configuration file.

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   }
```

How can i add the above bean in the configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should enable the components scanning. See Spring doc : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java

```
<beans>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.acme"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

From Pro Spring Mvc book:

> To config a `RequestDataValueProcessor`, we need to add it to the
>   application context and then register it with the name,
>   `requestDataValueProcessor`. This is the name the framework uses to
>   detect the registered instance.

So you probably need to do something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.bom"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public RequestDataValueProcessor
    requestDataValueProcessor() {
        return new DOMRequestDataValueProcessor();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean(name = { "requestDataValueProcessor" })
public DOMRequestDataValueProcessor getRequestDataValueProcessor() {
final DOMRequestDataValueProcessor domRequestDataValueProcessor = new DOMRequestDataValueProcessor();
        return domRequestDataValueProcessor;
    }
```